# Weird Unity prefab behaviour?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On a start of the scene, a script spawns 5 clones of a Prefab that includes :
A small rock with a collision detector and a big rock that itself includes : A sprite. For a better imagination Im providing a picture :

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

As you can see Big_rock in Rock element is connected properly in the prefab.

And whenever I want to use Destroy(Big_rock), it actually destroys the Big_rock **FROM THE NEXT PREFAB** and I have really no idea why it behaves like this.

Comment: Please add your code .. how are we supposed to know what happens there?

Comment: My code is literally only Destroy(Big_rock) as I said, the question isnt really about my code but rather why is unity behaving like this, why is it deleting something from the next prefab clone instead of its own clone

Comment: and where are those Instantiated? Hiw is that reference set? "Unity behaving strange" sometimes happens ofcourse but is almost always something wrong in the setup or code ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be that you are not changing the reference when instantiating the BigRock. 
BigRock, as a prefab, isn't the same as the GameObject that was spawned. You should have a second variable referring to the new spawned rock.

Remember that the first one doesn't exist on the scene, so you should save the one instantiated inside the scene.

```cs
// This will be the reference to the PREFAB
public GameObject big_rock;
// This will be the referenced to the new spawned gameobject
private GameObject spawned_big_rock;

private void SpawnRock()
{
    GameObject gameobjectThatWeJustSpawned = Instantiate(big_rock);
    // We set the reference to the one that was spawned
    spawned_big_rock = gameobjectThatWeJustSpawned;
}

public void DestroyRock()
{
    // We destroy the one that was spawned
    Destroy(spawned_big_rock);
}
```